# How to design a hotel booking system with a on hold feature

Tags: architecture, locking, system

I encountered this system design question in a interview and I didn't have the best answer.

The question is: we want to hold a room for 5 mins for a user, how do we do that?

The inventory data looks like this:

| Hotel-id | room_type_id | date | total_inventory | total_reserved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 001 | 2023-09-30 | 100 | 99 |
| 123 | 001 | 2023-10-01 | 100 | 96 |

The flow is once the user in the reservation detail page, the Reservation service first checked in cache for the inventory, then now there should be some kind of locking mechanism to lock a room for 5 mins. For 2023-09-30, there's still one room available so user A can proceed to the actual booking. If at the same time user B is trying to do the same thing, the system will know somehow there's a lock on this particular room type on this date and there is no more room available to book, hence the system will show "this room is not available"

My question is:

1. Should I say I can use Redis lock management to do this or something else?
2. How does the locking mechanism actually work? What is actually locking? i.e. Ideally I shouldn't lock the whole row correct? Because other users should be able to book the room when `total_inventory - total_reserved > 0`?

I mentioned we should probably use a lock to lock a room and set a TTL for 5 mins to release the lock. But I couldn't really explain clearly in step by step how it works. My guess is:

1. add an on-hold value in redis for each entry. For example

```
    key = 123_001_2023_09_30(hotel_id_room_type_id_date)
    value = { total_inventory: 100, total_reserved: 99, on_hold: 1}
    TTL = 5 mins
```

2. every time there's an other user trying to book, it should first check if `total_reserved + on_hold >= total_inventory`, if true, stop the user from proceeding to the next step
3. once the time is up (5 mins), redis would automatically decrease the on_hold by 1 (But is this doable??)

Is my answer far off from the real answer? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should check out the free online Redis RU101 course - it covers using Redis to reserve seats for a sporting event and timing out the reservations if the check out flow isn't completed fast enough.  Similar concepts.  Disclosure: I work at Redis and manage these courses. https://university.redis.com/courses/ru101/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is, each lock will have a different TTL.  So you really need a set of locks that expire.  You could do this by storing lock "keys" in redis, 1 for each lock with a TTL, and then scanning them to count them.  This isn't an ideal operation in Redis.  I'd actually consider a database of some sort which inserts hold rows with an explicit expiry time on them so that you can query it efficiently.  It will give you lots of downstream advantages such as being able to easily extend the hold time, and being able to do things like find out historically interesting things like conversion rates.